# Python UnbounLocalError : local variable "xxx" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables

it's a merge-sort algorithm in python

```
def MERGE_SORT(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = int((p+r)/2)
    MERGE_SORT(A, p, q)
    MERGE_SORT(A, q+1, r)
    MERGE(A, p, q, r)

def MERGE(A, p, q, r):
    n1 = q-p+1
    n2 = r-q
    L = []
    R = []
    for i in range(0, n1, 1):
        L[i] = A[p+i]
    for j in range(0, n2, 1):
        R[j] = A[q+j+1]
    L[n1]=float("inf")
    R[n2]=float("inf")
    i = 0 
    j = 0
    for k in range(p, r+1, 1):
        if L[i] < R[j] and L[i]==R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1
    return A
```

Comment: What's the actual error? Please post the full traceback

Comment: Please post the complete error as displayed in the shell. And what is "xxx"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def MERGE_SORT(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = int((p+r)/2)
    MERGE_SORT(A, p, q)
```

If `p < r` is `False`, `q` won't be defined, so you'll get an unbound local error on the following line. You need to define `q` in all cases.